# nth highest value from columnB against each unique value in columnA in DB2

Tags: db2, max

I have a table for employees name (as columnA) and their travel start date (as columnB). I want to get 3rd highest travel start date against each employees. If an employees travel count is less then 3 then their should be null value agaist that employee.
I am using DB2. Need help.
Thanx
Sample Tab
[Sample Table & Required Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VebxD.jpg)

Comment: Please add basic table schema and the query you tried. What was your result and what is the expected result? SQL is more fun with data

Comment: Table and required output added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ROWNUMBER will do the job - check out this query:

```
with temp (employee, travel_date, nth_oldest_travel) as (
select employee,
       travel_date,
       rownumber() over (partition by employee order by travel_date desc)
  from testemp
) 
select * from temp
where nth_oldest_travel = 3
```

Join it against the source if you need the null value for the employees that have less than 3 travels

Comment: Good to hear so please mark it as answer - this is how this forum works ...